Why is the flexbox container not changing position?
I'm trying to make a 2x2 flexbox container for my webpage that'll hold images and links to other parts of my website. I made the container, but I can't seem to get the container to move no matter what I do. I tried adjusting the margins, padding, and the position of it and nothing is adjusting the container's position.
CodePen: https://codepen.io/Dara-Jackson/pen/dyLZvKR


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.box {
  /* width: 100px;
  height: 100px; */
  background-color:#cccccc;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; */
  margin-top:1px;
  padding:200px;
}
<div class="nav">
  <a class="link"
      href="https://artfiles.rutgers.edu/~rad%5cdmj185/Dara%20-%20Portfolio%20Website%20%28WIP%29/index.html">Work</a>
  <a class="link"
      href="https://artfiles.rutgers.edu/~rad%5cdmj185/Dara%20-%20Portfolio%20Website%20%28WIP%29/about.html">About</a>
  <a class="link"
      href="https://artfiles.rutgers.edu/~rad%5cdmj185/Dara%20-%20Portfolio%20Website%20%28WIP%29/about.html">Contact</a>
</div>
<!-- end of nav bar -->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"><a href="https://artfiles.rutgers.edu/~rad%5cdmj185/Dara%20-%20Portfolio%20Website%20%28WIP%29/motion.html">Link 1</a></div>
    <div class="box"><a href="https://artfiles.rutgers.edu/~rad%5cdmj185/Dara%20-%20Portfolio%20Website%20%28WIP%29/visid.html">Link 2</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"><a href="https://artfiles.rutgers.edu/~rad%5cdmj185/Dara%20-%20Portfolio%20Website%20%28WIP%29/p5js.html">Link 3</a></div>
    <div class="box"><a href="https://artfiles.rutgers.edu/~rad%5cdmj185/Dara%20-%20Portfolio%20Website%20%28WIP%29/miscdesigns.html">Link 4</a></div>
  </div>
</div>




Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It's difficult to understand what you're asking. if you want to center the .container horizontally on the page. you can use margin: auto along with a fixed width.


.container {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
}
  
.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
  
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 16px;
    margin: 2px;
}
<div class="nav">
    <a class="link" href="#">Work</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box"><a href="#">Link 1</a></div>
        <div class="box"><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box"><a href="#">Link 3</a></div>
        <div class="box"><a href="#">Link 4</a></div>
    </div>
</div>




Thank you for your help! I apologize if my explanation of the problem was kinda vague or confusing. The setting the margins to auto and having the max-width made me understand how to further fix my code. Thanks again!

Thank you for your feedback! I'm glad the solution helped clarify things for you. If you found it helpful, would you mind giving it an upvote? Thanks again!

You don't see changing, because you have syntax error in your css, you need delete "*/" => screenshot

This answer for a typo error needs to be a comment

I can't comment, I don't have enough reputation yet
